# FastAPI passing params in get request via TestClient

Tags: python, pytest, fastapi

I'm currently working with FastAPI's TestClient and came across an unexpected behavior that I'd like some clarification on.

Working Example:

```py
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from fastapi import status

def my_func(client: TestClient) -> None:
   response = client.get(
       app.url_path_for("v1-my-endpoint"),
       params={"xx": "11", "yy": "22"}
   )
   assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK
```

Non-Working Example:

```py
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from fastapi import status

def my_func(client: TestClient) -> None:
   my_params={"xx": "11", "yy": "22"}
   response = client.get(
       app.url_path_for("v1-my-endpoint"),
       params=my_params
   )
   assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK
```

The second example, where I define parameters in a variable (my_params), throws the following error:

```
error: Argument "params" to "get" of "TestClient" has incompatible type "Dict[str, object]"; expected "Union[QueryParams, Mapping[str, Union[Union[str, int, float, bool, None], Sequence[Union[str, int, float, bool, None]]]], List[Tuple[str, Union[str, int, float, bool, None]]], Tuple[Tuple[str, Union[str, int, float, bool, None]], ...], str, bytes, None]"  [arg-type]
```

I'm curious about the difference in behavior between directly providing parameters and passing a variable containing the parameters. Why does the first example work while the second one throws an error? What's the recommended way to pass parameters when using TestClient in FastAPI?

Comment: I've just checked this and both these examples work. I don't get this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've encountered similar situations in my experience with FastAPI. The error you're encountering in the second example with FastAPI's TestClient is related to the type hinting and how Python's type checker (like mypy) interprets the type of the params argument.

In the working example, you directly pass a dictionary to the params argument. Here, Python's type inference correctly understands that the dictionary's keys and values are strings, so it matches the expected type for the params argument.

However, in the non-working example, when you define my_params as a variable and then pass it to params, the type checker is unable to infer the exact types of the keys and values in the dictionary. It defaults to Dict[str, object], which is a broader type than expected by TestClient.get(). The expected type for params is more specific, allowing not only strings but also integers, floats, booleans, and sequences of these types.

To resolve this issue, you can provide explicit type hints for your my_params dictionary to ensure it matches the expected type. Here's how you can modify your non-working example:

```
from typing import Dict, Union
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from fastapi import status

def my_func(client: TestClient) -> None:
    my_params: Dict[str, Union[str, int, float, bool, None]] = {"xx": "11", "yy": "22"}
    response = client.get(
        app.url_path_for("v1-my-endpoint"),
        params=my_params
    )
    assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK
```

By providing an explicit type hint for my_params, you inform the type checker about the specific type of each key and value in the dictionary. This should prevent the type error and make the second example work similarly to the first one.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow! Please note that use of AI Tools (e.g., ChatGPT) to generate or reword content that you post [is not permitted](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831) on Stack Overflow, even if you vet this content beforehand. Also see the related [Help](/help/ai-policy) on this topic. We do hope you'll stick around and continue to be a valuable member of the community by contributing your own quality answers and questions in the future!